# ...rest not working in Edge, React project

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, microsoft-edge, object-destructuring

```
handleSaveDefault = () => {
    let { Default, ...rest } = this.state.views;
    this.handleViewMenuClose();
    let setState = () => {
      return this.setState({
        views: { Default: [...this.state.selectedFields], ...rest },
      });
    };
```

This is working fine in chrome, but in Edge I get an error `Expected identifier, string or number` pointing to the ...rest in `let { Default, ...rest } = this.state.views;`

I read that ...rest wasn't supported in older versions of Edge but now it should be. I have updated Windows but still the error persists. I have babel installed and it shows up in my package-lock.json but not in package.json.

Is there a way to get this to work or do I have to create my own looping workaround?

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by updating Edge Legacy to Edge Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Edge are you using? Please check the Edge version in the browser setting. [Object rest/spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is not supported by Edge Legacy but supported by Edge Chromium. If you want to use the new Edge Chromium, you need to [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) and install it **manually**. Only updating Windows won't upgrade your Edge browser.

If you want to support the object rest/spread properties in Edge Legacy, you could refer to the following steps:

Install **@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread** by running:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

Then add it as plugins inside the package.json:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

For more detailed information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417760/react-cant-deconstruct-restprops-in-edge/60430889#60430889) and [this article](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread#usage).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to support the legacy version because I can't control my users. 

I ran your npm install and that added  `"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.9.5"
  }`

I am unsure where to add the plugins snipet you posted? My current package.jason doesn't have babel listed other than under devDependencies that I just added. babel is listed many times in package-lock.json but the file is too large to post. 

Where do I place `{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}` ?

Comment: I compared it with my former react project where `...rest` can work well, the issue is like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417760/react-cant-deconstruct-restprops-in-edge/60430889#60430889) says: react removed the babel-spread-operator in "babel-preset-react-app" (folder inside node_modules). I found a easy way to fix this, just **copy the babel-preset-react-app folder in former project and paste to replace the same folder in your new project.** Then the `...rest` can work well in Edge Legacy. FYI, the work-well babel-preset-react-app version for me is 9.0.2.